# Cursor not changing on MouseDown

Tags: delphi

I have a TPanel with 2 events:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Panel1.Cursor := crSizeAll;
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Panel1.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

When I click on the panel (MouseDown event) the cursor does not change to `crSizeAll`.
What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you moving the panel?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, no.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In that case my answer will be less useful unless you implement some more code.

Comment: Fixed that.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did all right. There is just a *simple trick* with capturing the mouse input. Once you've pressed Left Mouse Button (LMB) on `TPanel` this panel has got mouse unput.

After that happened, your code `Panel1.Cursor := crSizeAll;` is beginning to run. As you can see in the sources of VCL, `TControl` sends message `CM_CURSORCHANGED` to itself to set needed type of cursor. Since `TWinControl` is based on `TControl`, it handles this message and checks if mouse input has been captured. If this is not so, then `TWinControl` sends message `WM_SETCURSOR` to itself in order to set new cursor.

But Microsoft clearly stated that message `WM_SETCURSOR` has a little restriction:

> Sent to a window if the mouse causes the cursor to move within a window and **mouse input is not captured**.

So, there is no way to change cursor's type if mouse input has been captured. One thing you could do is to call `ReleaseCapture`:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ReleaseCapture;
  Panel1.Cursor := crSizeAll;
end;
```

But I wouldn't recommend do it this way since it breaks the paradigm of mouse input (in my opinion, once LMB was pressed, then it should stay pressed until it released by important reason (f.e. click on button), but you are free to decide how to use `ReleaseCapture` on your own).

**Important!**
Test executed by user *Zig* proved that using `ReleaseCapture` method is not appropriate since it forbids generating `OnMouseUp` event if mouse cursor gone outside of `TPanel` and LMB has been released.

Useful information:

1. [WM_SETCURSOR message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-setcursor)
2. [SetCapture function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture)
3. [GetCapture function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcapture)
4. [ReleaseCapture function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasecapture)

Comment: As an alternative to calling `ReleaseCapture()`, you can instead remove the `csCaptureMouse` flag from the Panel's `ControlStyle` property.

Comment: You are very close. problem with your solutsion is that `Panel1MouseUp` does not change to `crDefault`

Comment: @zig, I tested the code with using `ReleaseCapture`. `OnMouseUp` event works fine.

Comment: @Dima, My bad. your code worked. I'm only not sure abut `ReleaseCapture` is "healthy" in this situation. let me examine it...

Comment: using `ReleaseCapture` can have side effects: click on the panel, move outside the panel, release button, and the panel remains with `crSizeAll` cursor.

Comment: @zig, indeed. That's why I wasn't recommend to use it. I will add your feedback in my answer. So there are two ways: first is to be assured that mouse is *always* stays inside panel (cannot be really done unless you use [ClipCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clipcursor) function). Second one is to apply Remy's solution or use Sertac's method ;)

Comment: I wish I could accept all answers. You explained very well the "why" part which was very important to me. I ended up using Remy's simple solution combined with @Sertac's to give me the best effect I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As Dima [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784208/243614) the reason the `Cursor` setting of the panel does not have an effect is that, the panel cannot process `WM_SETCURSOR` messages since the mouse is captured as long as the mouse button is pressed.

To set the cursor immediately, you can use the `SetCursor` API. The possible downside is that the cursor will remain what you set until you release the mouse button, even outside the panel.

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crSizeAll]);
end;
```

You don't need to reset the cursor since the default will be assumed (in response to `WM_SETCURSOR` messages) after the mouse button is released.

---

If you want the cursor to revert outside of the panel and set again when it enters on the panel again, you can include an `OnMouseMove` event handler. That's because mouse messages will be directed to the panel even when outside the panel since it captured the mouse:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if Mouse.Capture = Panel1.Handle then begin
    if PtInRect(Rect(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height), Point(X, Y)) then
      SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crSizeAll])
    else
      SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crDefault])
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Setting `Screen.Cursor` calls `SetCursor()` internally, so this code is effectively the same as doing `Screen.Cursor := crSizeAll;` instead.

Comment: @Remy - Ok. There's still a little difference in that since this doesn't set the Screen.Cursor, no need to revert it back.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Actually your method with `MouseMove` combined with @Remy's solution, gives the most effective result IMO. e.g the cursor changes to `crSizeAll` right away when the Mouse is down, and reverts to `crDefault` when draging the mouse and it goes outside the panel bounds. Thanks :)

Comment: @zig - You're welcome. I wonder if the OnMouseDown code in this answer not work for you? It should change the cursor rather immediately..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, You are correct. I assumed `SetCursor` will have the same effect as `Screen.Cursor` but the difference you described is valid. Your solution is actually perfect, but like I mentioned in a comment, @Dima provided a perfect explanation about the reason, and I simply can't accept more than one answer :/ I really hope you don't mind me accepting his answer. many thanks mate!

Comment: Thanks. No problem with the accept, actually it was a nice idea, pity that it didn't work out.

Answer (score 8):

Dima explained why changing `Panel1.Cursor` does not have the effect you want.

As an alternative, you can change the `Screen.Cursor` instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseDown(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crSizeAll;
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1MouseUp(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I combined your method with @SertacAkyuz and it gave me the most effective results.

Comment: I think I recommend against this approach, since you are setting a global state variable (`Screen.Cursor`) to solve a local problem (the cursor of one specific panel). For instance, if you press the mouse button on this panel and then press Ctrl+Alt+Del to switch desktop, release the mouse button in the Ctrl+Alt+Del desktop, and then go back to your app, you will find that you are stuck with the `crSizeAll` cursor (on every control, not just the panel).